# Preprocessing and dummy variables order of procedure?

Tags: r, categorical-data, caret, data-preprocessing

I would please like to know when I should conduct pre-processing procedures (removing near-zero variance, highly correlated predictor variables, and linear dependencies) when planning to create dummy variables from factor variables. I am using R and the caret package.

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: See [page 550](https://books.google.com/books?id=xYRDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA547&lpg=PA547&dq=applied%20predictive%20modeling,%20table%20a1&source=bl&ots=qQnlJOoB_a&sig=HOo3gyJULZ2Sn0eJ9z6fwpTdLVw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ImSjVNDTO9CWyAT8q4KoAw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=applied%20predictive%20modeling%2C%20table%20a1&f=false) of Max Kuhn's book *Applied Predictive Modeling*. He's also the author of caret BTW.